# After hitting a curb, besides alignment, what else should be checked for damage

Tags: wheels, suspension, alignment, wheel-bearing, suspension-geometry

I'm positive the alignment is  shot- so that's the first repair.

But what else might be a potential problem, in theory?

(Not asking for a diagnosis over the internet- just wanting to get a general idea of what else could typically go wrong in such a scenario.)

Bent rim?

Wheel bearing damage?

Damaged suspension components?

Just trying to get an idea of what could also potentially be problematic, besides alignment, since the car now shakes while driving at highway speeds (over 50).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track for sure. Alignment isn't always a source of vibration, you'd also likely be getting pulling or control problems too. Vibration could be something else:

- Wheel: the wheel could get bent or cracked with an impact. This would definitely cause vibration. You generally can't fix a wheel, so you'd need to replace it. It's also possible an impact caused weights to be shed which would also cause vibration, but less likely to occur
- Tire: an impact could damage the tire sidewall. This may not immediately be noticeable, but could lead to a later catastrophic failure.  It's possible a bad tire could cause vibration, as damage can cause the tire to change shape
- Suspension components: A bent suspension member cause cause vibration for the same reason a bad alignment can. It's also possible that a suspension mount has been damaged, or that the joint between suspension members has been damaged. That would take a pretty big impact
- Frame damage: a very serious impact could possibly cause the car's frame to bend. This is pretty unlikely though, I'm putting it in for completeness
- Wheel bearings: a curb hit can definitely crack a wheel bearing. It's unlikely that will cause vibration, you're more likely to hear it as a grinding or whining that increases in pitch and vibration with speed